# How do I upload both an Image and a document to Firebase Storage, get the download URLs and insert them into the realtime database simultaneously?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I am developing an application where a user can upload an image, and also a document. I can do write the code for uploading the image and that of the document separately, but what I want is to be able to upload an image and a document, get their download Urls place them in the realtime database at the same time. the code below is for uploading an image, how can I change it so that I can also upload a document and save the download URL in the same node as the image?

```
final StorageReference fileReference = storageReference.child(System.currentTimeMillis() + "." + getFileExtension(resultUri));
        uploadTask = fileReference.putFile(resultUri);
        uploadTask.continueWithTask(new Continuation(){
            @Override
            public Object then(@NonNull Task task) throws Exception {
                if (!task.isComplete()){
                    throw Objects.requireNonNull(task.getException());
                }
                return fileReference.getDownloadUrl();
            }
        }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task <Uri> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()){
                    Uri downloadUri = task.getResult();
                    myUrl = downloadUri.toString();
                        String postid = reference.push().getKey();
                        
                        HashMap<String, Object> hashMap =   new HashMap<>();
                        hashMap.put("image", myUrl);
               //maybe add here the url of the document
                       //Is it possible to upload an image and a document, get their download Urls place them in the realtime database at the same time?
                       //hashMap.put("document", documentUrl);  
                        hashMap.put("publisher",FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
                        hashMap.put("date", mDate);

                        reference.child(postid).setValue(hashMap);
                        loader.dismiss();
                        startActivity(new Intent(AskAQuestionActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                        finish();
                   
                }else {
                    String error = task.getException().toString();
                    Toast.makeText(AskAQuestionActivity.this, "Failed" + error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(AskAQuestionActivity.this, "Question could not be posted." , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No image is selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

Any Help will be really appreciated. Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I upload both an Image and a document to firebase storage, get the download URLs, and insert them into the realtime database simultaneously?

If you are thinking at a batch operation where you can add a Firebase Realtime Database `setValue()` operation and a Firebase Storage `putFile()` operation and make them work simultaneously, please note that this is **not** possible. These operations are apart of different Firebase services. Unfortunately, none of the Firebase products support cross-product transactional operations. So the only option that you have is the one that you are already using.